# How to prevent query execution after exiting the \e editor in psql?

Tags: postgresql, psql

Is there an option that can change the "exit external editor -> query runs automatically" behaviour of the psql \e switch ?  (Other than intentionally mangling the query syntax).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't add a **semicolon** (`;`). I quote the manual about the `\e` or `\edit` meta-command [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html):

> The new contents of the query buffer are then re-parsed according to
> the normal rules of psql, treating the whole buffer as a single line.
> Any complete queries are immediately executed; that is, if the query
> buffer contains or ends with a semicolon, everything up to that point
> is executed and removed from the query buffer. Whatever remains in the
> query buffer is redisplayed. Type semicolon or `\g` to send it, or
> `\r` to cancel it by clearing the query buffer.

To be clear: only the last statement that is not terminated with a semicolon is not executed. To execute ***nothing at all***, make sure there are no complete statements before the last statement. I.e. no semicolons at all.

That's really unsatisfying, though. See this follow-up:

- [Reckless behavior of psql \e](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/280580/reckless-behavior-of-psql-e?noredirect=1&lq=1)

.. which led Laurenz Albe to commit [some improvements](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=55873a00e3c3349664e7215077dca74ccea08b4d), live in psql 14 or later.

Comment: Just `\r` solves after editor exit.

Answer (score 0):

You can always prefix the query with the postgres comment string:

```
--select foo from bar;
```

and the query will not run but will be available in the psql deadline history buffer for editing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have many request and some semicolons use Transaction :

In psql open editor mode `\e`:

```
-- at start of edited text 
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
-- ...  your requests here
-- save exit
```

Back to psql : your requests are executed but change are not written :

If all is OK, save changes with :

```
COMMIT;
```

else If you have errors or want to cancel :

```
ROLLBACK;
```