# Reckless behavior of psql \e

Tags: postgresql, psql

`psql` 13.2 executes the query buffer no matter what when exiting the editor, even after quitting it - in which case the buffer may hold the most recently executed SQL query now.

To reproduce:

1. Start editor (`vim` in my case) with `\e` or `\e filename` from the `psql` console.
2. Type something or not, doesn't make a difference.
3. Cancel edit with `:q` (or `:q!` to force it)

Expected behavior: go back to the state before starting the editor. (I cancelled the edit!)
Observed behavior: re-execute the last executed SQL query.

What seems to happen with `\e`:

1. it executes (the equivalent of) `\p`, so the current query buffer contains the previous command when it was empty. (Which is not visible to the user when editing a file!)
   [The manual  on `\p` :](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS)

   > `\p` or `\print`
   >
   > Print the current query buffer to the standard output. If the current query buffer is empty, the most recently executed query is printed instead.
2. Start up the editor. If a filename was provided, load the file, else, load the query buffer.
3. If the editor ends with a write, copy the result to the query buffer.
   If the edit is cancelled (`:q` in vim), don't overwrite the query buffer. (It holds the previous command now!)
4. Execute the query buffer. Or, to be precise, do this:

   - [How to prevent query execution after exiting the \e editor in psql?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31388/how-to-prevent-query-execution-after-exiting-the-e-editor-in-psql/31397#31397)

The behavior seems ok for `\p` (just copy the query buffer, no harm done), but not for `\e`, which can execute a command I didn't even get to see.

Is it a bug?
Either way, I would at least like to disable auto-execute when leaving the editor. But that doesn't seem to be possible. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has been [fixed in v14](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=55873a00e3c3349664e7215077dca74ccea08b4d) as a reaction to this question. The rest of the answer refers to the pre-v14 behavior:

This is (sort of) [documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-psql.html):

> If `filename` is specified, the file is edited; after the editor exits, the file's content is copied into the current query buffer. If no `filename` is given, the current query buffer is copied to a temporary file which is then edited in the same fashion. Or, if the current query buffer is empty, the most recently executed query is copied to a temporary file and edited in the same fashion.
>
> The new contents of the query buffer are then re-parsed according to the normal rules of psql, treating the whole buffer as a single line.

If you quit the editor without saving, it is the current query buffer or the most recently executed query that are executed.

I agree with you that this is annoying, and you are not the first person I heard complain.

When editing a script, the behavior clearly violates the “principle of least astonishment”:

```
test=> \! cat q.sql
SELECT 99;

test=> SELECT 42;
 ?column? 
----------
       42
(1 row)

test=> \e q.sql
 ?column? 
----------
       42
(1 row)
```

Comment: Excellent! I did not test yet, but judging from code & discussion, you seem to have fixed this - and some more that surfaced. Kudos!